# How to ignore duplicates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a 'newbie' at MySQL, so I don't know how to correctly execute INSERT IGNORE in MySQL.

I'm developing a website with referral system that is linked to MySQL. I want to allow the same referral code to be used an unlimited number of times.
I am getting an error "Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'ref0001' for key 'referral'"

How do I use INSERT IGNORE?

Thanks in advance, i will really appreciate your help <3

Comment: Please provide more details, and preferably sample code to give us an idea of what your database table looks like and how you are attempting to query it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: oh, i forgot to put my table details: table name - users, the column for referrals is "referrals"

Comment: here's a screenshot of table https://prnt.sc/fuvusi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put a `UNIQUE` constraint (perhaps explicitly, perhaps implicitly via `PRIMARY KEY`) on the `referral` field. This means that you can only have one record in that table with a specific value in the `referral` field. If you want to be able to have multiple rows with the same value for the `referral` field, then you need to remove the `UNIQUE` constraint. If `referral` is defined as `PRIMARY KEY` then you have some more serious database design to worry about.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but please, can you explain how to remove the UNIQUE constraint?